# Powershell Dot Slash .\ Starts at the root of a drive

Tags: powershell

Note: I'm using the built-in PowerShell ISE as my environment

I got a funny issue with dot slash on Powershell. All of my scripts run from a certain folder and there are subfolders that contain data that is needed for them to run.

For example, my scripts are saved at c:\users\chris\posh
Most of the time, I will call input and send output to subfolders like this...

```
c:\users\chris\posh\inputs
c:\users\chris\posh\output
```

Therefore I'll have scripts examples that look like this for inputs and outputs:

```
$hbslist = Get-Content .\inputs\HBS-IP.txt

write-output "$($lat),$($long)" | Out-File .\Outputs\"LatLong.csv" -Append
```

Lately, when I run the scripts, it cannot locate my files or exe's that I call on. That's because it's trying to look at `P:/` instead of `c:\users\chris\posh` when using `.\`

Powershell also starts in my `P:\` (mapped share drive) for some reason and I cannot figure out as to why my PC is running this way.

Comment: How are you running the scripts exactly?

Comment: If it can help, `$PSScriptRoot` resolves to folder where the PS1 (or psm1) file lives. You can build paths using something like `$dataPath = "$PSScriptRoot\Data\myinput.csv"`. It even supports relative path : `$dataPath = "$PSScriptRoot\..\Data\myinput.csv"`

Comment: This solves my problem! Thank you! Now I can package these up and run them where ever I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a policy on your machine which changes your home directory. You can check the home directory with:

```
echo $env:HOME
```

This happens often on corporate machines. If you want to set it back for your powershell environment, you can set it in your profile.ps1.

This is typically stored at:

```
c:\Users\<Name>\Documents\WindowsPowershell\profile.ps1
```

Comment: Good to know. Thank you!

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it. If it doesn't please clarify your question.